# Is there a way to do a clean windows 10 installation using my Microsoft account but without copying my old user settings?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-account

I have been using windows 8/10 for some time now and I also have a MS account. That means that every time I do a new installation, my settings are copied across devices. I bought a new laptop and even though I want to use the same MS account, I don't want to copy the settings from my desktop machine. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: have you tried creating a recovery drive from within windows 10 and selecting to not backup files?

Comment: I think recovery of settings happens via cloud

Comment: ah - you can disable Sync within your Sync Settings so you can do a clean account setup without copying files/settings/prefs

Comment: so disable syncing and then do a clean installation?

Comment: yes - this should work the same way disabling chrome sync works - it will allow you to start fresh without importing cloud data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by going into Systems Settings -> Accounts and turning off Sync Settings - This will allow you to, when installing a fresh version of Windows, to setup your account how you like, without importing settings from a previous install.